# Data loss somewhere by plotting maps with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

Here is my data:

The shapefiles can be downloaded here [Swiss Federal Office of Topography](http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/en/home/products/landscape/swissBOUNDARIES3D.html).

Data on the appropriate level can be downloaded [here](http://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/portal/de/index/themen/17/03/blank/key/2014/032.Document.185872.xls).

Here's my code:

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(rgdal)   
library(ggplot2)

#load map
map.gem<- readOGR(dsn="path to your shapefile", layer="VEC200_Commune")


data <- data.frame(id=rownames(map.gem@data),
               BEZNR=map.gem@data$BEZIRKSNR)

data$id <- as.character(data$id)

bez <- read.csv("~/586.csv", sep=";")

#bez should look like this:
head(bez)
BEZNR    res_586
101      30.76
102      29.53
103      28.56
104      27.71
105      29.42
106      28.96

data1  <- merge(data, bez, by="BEZNR")
map.df <- fortify(map.gem)
map.df <- join(map.df, data1, by="id")
```

Usually this procedure works well (thanks go @jlhoward), but this time I lose data along the way.

Here's the ggplot part:

```
ggplot(data=map.df, aes(long,lat, group=group))+
geom_polygon(aes(fill=res_586))+
coord_fixed()+
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "palevioletred3", high = "cadetblue", guide = "colourbar")+
theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())
```

Some of the grey regions are lakes, this is no problem. But the main region in the heart of the map gives me a headache. I hope someone can give me a hint, altough I'm not quite sure if this question even belongs here.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

The problem seems to be that some of the Polygons in the shapefile have district nr. (BEZIRKSNR) = 0. Some of these are lakes, but many are not. You can see this as follows:

```
map.sub <- with(map.gem@data,map.gem[BEZIRKSNR==0&COUNTRY=="CH"&SEENAME=="N/A",])
ggplot(map.sub,aes(long,lat,group=group))+geom_polygon(fill="red")+coord_fixed()
```

[image]

The code above subsets the map to include only districts in Switzerland with `BEZIRKSNR==0` and no `SEENAME`. You can see which districts these are using:

```
unique(map.sub@data$GEMNAME)
```

Since none of your polling data have BEZNR=0, those areas have `NA` values for res_589. I have no idea why these districts do not have a BEZIRKSNR.

Comment: Thank you once more for your helpful comment! I have no idea, why the BEZIRKSNR==0. I manually added the true values like this: `map.gem@data$BEZIRKSNR[map.gem@data$KANTONSNR==4&map.gem@data$COUNTRY=="CH"] <- 400` etc.